# deleting stock apps on os x programmatically

Tags: macos, root, osx-elcapitan

Does anyone know if there’s a way to delete stock apps on 10.11 programmatically without disabling SIP and rebooting the machine?  Or, is there a way to disable SIP without rebooting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a kernel signing certificate, you can disable SIP without rebooting with [Rootfool](https://github.com/gdbinit/rootfool). You'll need to compile it yourself.

Rootfool tool uses a kernel extension, which will only be loaded by the kernel if it's signed, or if SIP is turned off.

Without the signing certificate, no, you can't delete any of Apple's system files with SIP turned on. SIP is there to protect from the operating system being corrupt by malware, or accidental deletion and Apple has included its own applications as being protected by SIP.